# get_tags wordpress function issue

Tags: wordpress

Following code always outputs "Foo" regardless of whether the tag count is greater than 50 or not.

What is wrong with my syntax? Thanks.

```
$posttags = get_tags();
if ($posttags) {
                    foreach($posttags as $tag) {
                          if (intval($tag->count) > 50);{   
                            echo "Foo";

                          }
```

Comment: I would add print_r($tag->count) before the if (inside the foreach) to see what can possibly cause the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a superfluous `;` after your `if`

```
if (intval($tag->count) > 50);{
                             ^
```

Just remove it

```
if (intval($tag->count) > 50){
```

The way it is now it basically says: "if count > 50 do nothing. Then do the `echo "Foo"` in the brackets."